Quick Connect Fitting Not Compatible with Hose Bib?
I just bought a quick connect set and it screws on easily at both ends.  But, then I couldn't get the two ends to mate up.
Out of frustration I unscrewed everything and figured out there's a valve inside the quick connect.  The valve stem won't clear the annoying plastic pin in my hose bib when I try to mate the new fittings.
Is there a way to make this work?




The centre piece is only useful if someone wacks the quick connect with a baseball bat with the faucet open.  It stops flow when the second half is not connected.  Like what the faucet handle does.

@crip659 Yeah the whole thing is less convenient than advertised.  Is it designed to go on the male end of the hose only?

@RobertChapin yes, it is not designed to allow quick changing from one hose to another.  It is designed to allow quick changing of accessories on the end of the hose.  The idea of the valve is that you can do it while the water is on.  But it never works.  The pressure makes it too difficult to push the new accessory on, and you get a brief but very annoying spray in the face when you do it.

Your hose bib has a backflow preventer attached to it. It is required by code in some areas. If not required, they are still a good idea.
The quick-connect that you have has a shut-off feature (the valve that is opened when the mate is attached). You can buy them without the shut off feature. You really don't need this feature at the hose bib end.
I often can't find quick-connects without shut-off at my local store. I knock out the quick connect valve with a large nail and hammer.

I never thought of knocking out the valve.  It's a great idea.  They are a PIA and you can't use the QC anyway if the valve is under pressure.  It's too hard to push the components together, and you get sprayed when you do it.. They also prevent your hose from depressurizing after use, which shortens their life.   Can't wait to try this

Genius level answer here.  Large nail not required.  I grabbed the fattest flat head screwdriver in my collection, and with a surprisingly light tap by a hammer that valve piece popped right out!

The white pin is part of a vacuum breaker.  This prevents water flowing from the hose back into your house pipes.
If a vacuum breaker is mandated by local law or if there is a good reason you need one there, replace it with one that does not have a plastic pin in the middle.  They don't all have one.  If the vacuum breaker is neither mandated nor needed, just remove it.
Another option is to attach a hose bib extender to the existing vacuum breaker, then the male half of your QC to that.  Extenders are basically very short rubber hoses, just inches. They can be solid brass, or rubber with a metal spring wrapped around them, or just literally a very short rubber hose.
[Bear in mind, yet another option, in the other answer, is my new favorite ....]
